# Communicate between components outside of hierarchy (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have scoured the docs on how to do what I want but to no avail. I have a dynamic form component that is a child route of the parent object. For example, here is the path for the user profile and the edit user profile form:

```
{
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: FormComponent,
            data: {
                form_title: 'Edit Profile',
                action: 'current_user',
                method: 'put'
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

I am trying to use the method here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

It is not working though. I think the problem is that I am injecting different instances of the same service to communicate so there is not an actual "connection" between the components.

Here are my components and my service I am trying to communicate with:

ProfileComponent:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'profile',
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile.component.html',
    providers: [ FormControlService ]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnDestroy{
    private user: User;
    private profile_sub: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private auth: AuthenticationService,
        private fcs: FormControlService
    ){
        this.user = auth.getUser();
        this.profile_sub = fcs.resourceUpdated$.subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
            console.log(user); //nothing is logged to console here
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.profile_sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

FormComponent (dumbed down to show the relevant parts, important part is onSubmit() function)

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'nw-form',
    templateUrl: 'templates/form.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'css/form.component.css' ],
    providers: [ FormControlService ]
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
    private fields: FormItem<string | Object>[][];
    private form_title: string;
    private form: FormBaseClass;
    private model_sub: Subscription;
    private submit_sub: Subscription;

    formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private fcs: FormControlService,
        //...removed irrelevant code...//
    ) {
        //...sets up form and populates fields if necessary...//
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if(this.model_sub) this.model_sub.unsubscribe();
        if(this.submit_sub) this.submit_sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    onSubmit() {
        //this is where I am trying to send data back to the profile component
        this.fcs.updateResource(this.formGroup.value);

    }


}
```

FormControlService (also dumbed down to important parts)

```
@Injectable()
export class FormControlService {
    private savedSource = new Subject<any>();

    resourceUpdated$ = this.savedSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private clientForm: ClientForm,
        private profileForm: ProfileForm
    ) {}

    updateResource(resource: any): void {
        this.savedSource.next(resource);
    }
    //...more functions go here...//
}
```

With my router setup, is there a better way to do this? I would rather not have to use the form component as a directive inside the profile component, but if that is the only way I may just have to adjust my code to suit.

Angular 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't provide the service on the component. Each component instance will get a different instance.

Instead provide it in

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [BrowserModule, ..., FormControlService],
  ....
})
export class AppModule /* or SubModule */ {}
```

Comment: Ah yes! I could've sworn I tried it that way before but was getting the "No provider for FormControlService" error so I ended up injecting it separately to both. Makes perfect sense why it didn't work like that.